# Terminal test command is not working as expected in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, shell, cocoa

When I run following shell command either on terminal or as a shell script:

```
test -f test.dmg && rm test.dmg
```

> Output: It deletes test.dmg, if presents in the current directory.

However, while running the same command in swift as below, its not working as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [AnyObject] = []) -> String? {
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = launchPath
        task.arguments = (arguments as! [String])
        print(task.arguments)

        let pipe = NSPipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(output)
        return (output as! String)
    }

    let arguments = ["test", "-f", "test.dmg", "&&", "rm", "test.dmg"]
    shell("/bin/sh", arguments)
```

> Output with swift: **test: test: is a directory**

Can somebody help with this?

Comment: Do you have a directory `test` in the current directory? Should you be using the `-c` flag (and then passing the actual commands as a single string argument to the `-c` flag)?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, I had test folder in the current directory. However, this -c flag did the trick though I need to pass complete command as single string argument. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.

The reason for the error is because you have a `test` directory in the current directory and (because of the second error) the shell is trying to execute it as a script and failing.

The second error is that you don't pass commands to the shell to run directly as independent arguments.

That is you **don't** do this:

```
/bin/sh test -f test.dmg && rm test.dmg
```

What you do is you use the `-c` flag to the shell and pass the *entire* command as a single string to it:

```
/bin/sh -c 'test -f test.dmg && rm test.dmg'
```

Which would make your code something like this:

```
let arguments = ["-c" "test -f test.dmg && rm test.dmg"]
shell("/bin/sh", arguments)
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I did in the same way after you suggested. thnx